# Horizontal lines (top and bottom of text)

Tags: box, horizontal

I am a beginner and trying to re-create something that looks like the below. Please can someone help?

Thanks

[image]

---

If I use the following code

```
\begin{centering}
\hrule

\title{$title$}

\hrule
\end{centering}
```

It renders as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is this for your chapter title? If yes, it looks like something from the FncyChap package

Comment: The answer may vary depending on the document class and/or the type of text where you want the rules (the document title, a chapter, plaint text, the header  ...).  Please explain what are you trying to do exactly.

Answer (score -1):

```
\hrule
```

or

```
\hline
```

Enclose your text with in these two commands.